# What are the rules for naming AS3 classes?

Tags: actionscript-3, naming, convention

I'm trying to write a RegEx for a code generator (in C#) to determine a proper class or package name of an AS3 class.

I know that class names

- must start with a letter (capital or otherwise)
- any other digit can be alphanumeric
- cannot have spaces

Is there anything else?

Answer (score 3):

Although you can start class names with lower case letters and include underscores and dollar signs, the "naming **convention**" is to start the class name and each separate word with a capital letter (e.g. UsefulThing), and not include underscores. When I see classes like `useful_thing`, it looks wrong, because it's not the naming **convention**. Maybe your question should have said what are the **valid** names for an AS3 class?

Other than that I think you + maclema have it.

Answer (score 2):

The conventions for Class and Package naming as far as I've heard:

The package structure should use the "flipped domain" naming, with lowercase folders and CamelCased class names, i.e.:

```
import com.yourdomain.nameofsubfolder.YourSpecialClass;
```

This is reflected in all of the packages shipped with Flash and Flex. Examples:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
```

There is also a convention of naming Interfaces after the functionality they add or impose as in: `Styleable`, `Drawable`, `Movable` etc... Many (including Adobe) also prefer to use an upper case "I" to mark interfaces clearly as such, i.e.:

```
IEventDispatcher
IExternalizable 
IFocusManager
```

which are all internal interfaces in the `flash.*` packages.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more valid classes.

Actionscript 3 classes (and packages) must start with a letter, "_", or "$". They may also contain (but not start with) a number.

```
public class $Test {}
public class _Test {}
public class test {}
```